# Base64 Encoding/Decoding with Swift 2

Tags: base64, swift2, ios9

My code was working well on Xcode 6.4 with Swift 1.2:

```
 var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(firstImageView.image!, 0.2)

 let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
```

Once I moved to Xcode 7 and Swift 2 the following error appeared:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

So I tried:

```
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(options: NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.allZeros)
```

But there is no "allZeros" option among NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` instead of `.allZeros`:

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(firstImageView.image!, 0.2)

let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```