# New Swift Way For Base64EncodedStringFromData Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, base64

I am converting Objective-C to Swift and ran into code that is turning an Apple  App Store receipt NSData into a base64 encoded string.

The code is using the function **Base64EncodedStringFromData** from https://github.com/stackmob/stackmob-ios-sdk/blob/master/Utility/Base64EncodedStringFromData.m

From a stackoverflow post titled [Base64 Encoding/Decoding with Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967765/base64-encoding-decoding-with-swift-2), I see how to encode NSData.

```
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

However, I think I should do the following instead if I want the result to be the same as the Base64EncodedStringFromData function:

```
let base64String = transactionReceipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

Are the **"Base64EncodedStringFromData"** and transactionReceipt.**base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])** equivalent? I plan on experimenting. However, I want to make sure the concept is correct.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I'd like to point out that in Swift, you can drop the Enumeration type name before the Enumeration value. You could write just `.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` and `NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength` will be inferred

Comment: Experimentation shows that our server and Apple takes the replacement Swift code of transactionReceipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) just fine.

Comment: Thank you @AMomchilov for pointing out that the .Encoding64CharacterLineLength would be inferred. I decided to leave it in there since it's a quote from another supporting post.

Answer (score 1):

Are these two equivalent? - The answer is no, but it depends on the length of your string.

If you take a look on the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/base64EncodedStringWithOptions:), it clearly states, if you not specify a line length, than the encoding will be Carriage Return + Line Feed.

Also, i have written a small test to take a look, because i am also using base64 encoding.

```
 let someShortString = "someShortString"
 let encodedShortString = someShortString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


 let someLongString = "someLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongStringsomeLongString"
 let encodedLongString = someLongString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

 let base64ShortStringWithoutParameters = encodedShortString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
 let base64ShortStringWithParameters = encodedShortString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)


 let base64LongStringWithoutParameters = encodedLongString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
 let base64LongStringWithParameters = encodedLongString.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

 base64ShortStringWithoutParameters == base64ShortStringWithParameters ? print("same") : print("not same")
 base64LongStringWithoutParameters == base64LongStringWithParameters ? print("same") : print("not same")
```

It will print "same" for the first statement and "not same" for the second one.

So in conclusion, if your string is longer than a certain length(what might be 64 characters, but i am not sure), they will not be the same. There will be "\r\n" inserted into the converted string.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I expanded the question from "Are these two equivalent?" to Are the "Base64EncodedStringFromData" and transactionReceipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) equivalent?  I apologize. The question of "Are these two equivalent" was too vague.